# edit a text file in an uncompressed .tar

Tags: bash, awk, sed, tar

I have created some `.tar` folders that for the most part contain some text files. Is is possible to edit programmatically a text file from the command line (`bash` and related tools) without fully un-packing the tar?

Context: these `.tar`s were created by a script and I realized I made a mistake. I'm looking for the most efficient and simple solution to edit a part of a single line of a text file.

Comment: I can imagine the feasibility of such an edit that does not change the length of the edited string. For example, `perl -pi -e 's/echo var1/echo var2/g' compressed.tar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `tar --delete` and `tar --update` to replace a file inside a tar

Answer (score 1):

Thanx for the inspiration Grammy, here is a minimal example in case someone comes looking for the same.
Create some data in a folder:

```
cd /tmp; 
mkdir dir1; 
echo "foo" >> ./dir1/test_txt; 
echo "bar" >> ./dir1/test_txt;
```

Pack in a tar:

```
tar -cf test_tar.tar dir1;
```

Delete the directory that we are going to decompress and edit.

```
rm -rf dir1;
```

And unpack only the relevant file from the tar folder and edit:

### WARNING:

#### Tar updates only if the timestamp changed since the last edit!

This is why there is a sleep command here (to change the timestamp.).

```
sleep 1
tar -xf test_tar.tar dir1/test_txt
sed -i 's/foo/baar/' dir1/test_txt ;
```

Update the relevant file.

```
tar -uf test_tar.tar dir1/test_txt
```

Check if this worked:

```
tar -xf test_tar.tar dir1
cat ./dir1/test_txt

[...]$ 
baar
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you won't be able do it with out descompressing. You could to do a loop for descompress only your text file, edit with sed and compress again. In other case, i think that it is impossible...

maybe something like this

```
xzcat blah | sed /../../ | xz blah
```

within the loop that runs through all the files